# Calculate average value over last hundred rows of a column

Tags: r, data.table

Here is a quick hack to calculate the average of x over the last 3 rows:

```
s <- data.table(x=c(.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.1))
s$avgx = NA
for(i in (4:10)) s$avgx[i] <- mean(s$x[(i-1):(i-3)])
s
      x avgx
 1: 0.1  NA
 2: 0.2  NA
 3: 0.3  NA
 4: 0.4  0.2 # 0.2 is average of x in previous 3 rows
 5: 0.5  0.3 # etc.
 6: 0.6  0.4
 7: 0.7  0.5
 8: 0.8  0.6
 9: 0.9  0.7
10: 0.1  0.8
```

This code works, but gets very slow for large data (100k rows, average over last 100 or 1000 rows, for example).

Is there a quick way to do this, either with data table, or data frame?

Comment: `rollmean` in the `zoo` package will give you rolling means.

Comment: How does `zoo::rollmean` perform for large datasets?

Comment: I timed it with the `microbenchmark` package and it took about 1/20th the time of the for loop on a small dataset. I also ran `rollmean` with a window size of 3 on a vector of 1e5 values and it took 0.25 seconds.

Comment: My answer below runs almost instantly (<0.1s) for runif(100000) rolling over 1000 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zoo::rollmean()` does most of what you're after, it's just a case of lining up the rows as you want:

```
> rollmean(s$x, 3, na.pad=TRUE, align="right")
 [1]  NA  NA 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.6

> means <- rollmean(s$x, 3, na.pad=TRUE, align="right")
> c(NA, means[-length(means)])
 [1]  NA  NA  NA 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
```